# Unable to insert single row in oracle using cx_Oracle in python

Tags: python-2.7

code snip :

```
    statement = 'insert into my_Table ("DATE_TS","first_name","Last_name","pet_name","Salary") values (:2, :3, :4,:5,:6)'
    cur=conn.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute(statement, ('2016-25-07','te','ee','cd',21))
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
    finally:
        print "Closing Connection"
        conn.close()
```

i tried to insert this doing multiple combinations with the date(double quotes,single quotes,without quotes etc) but every time an error pops up ....kindly guide me ...have searched for almost 6 hours and getting nowhere with this

Comment: The error and the CREATE TABLE for the statement would be useful.  You probably need a TO_DATE using the correct format for your globalization & date configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
statement = 'insert into my_Table ("DATE_TS","first_name","Last_name","pet_name","Salary") values (to_date(:2, \'YYYY-DD-MM\'), :3, :4,:5,:6)'
```